# open an mvc 4 view from javascript in a new window

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to open a new window (window.open) using javascript in mvc 4.  Here's my current code:

```
                var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "ReportExecution", new {target="_blank"})';
            window.location.href = url;
```

This doesn't open a new window.  It makes the url "ReportExecution/Index?target=_blank".  I tried using:

```
window.open
```

instead of

```
window.location.href
```

but that didn't work.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so this code works for opening a new MVC 4 view in javascript:

```
window.open('@Url.Action("Index", "ReportExecution")');
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine but `new {target="_blank"})` is redundant.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "ReportExecution")';
   window.open(url, '_blank');
</script>
```

Comment: As you can see from my answer, you can't use `target="_blank"`.  It's not redundant, it actually becomes the parameters of the url.  If you look at my answer I did what you did to fix it only in shorter form.